# I want to place a particular value at top of the cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to place a particular value from the server at the top of the table view i.e. the first row 
I want to place feedback from the user at the top of the table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllFeedbackCell", for: indexPath) as? AllFeedbackCell {
            cell.feedback = feedbacks?[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

```
 var feedback: Feedback? {
        didSet {
            if let username = feedback?.username, !username.isEmpty {
                userEmailLabel.text = username
            } else {
                if let userEmail = feedback?.email, let emailIndex = userEmail.range(of: "@")?.upperBound {
                    userEmailLabel.text = String(userEmail.prefix(upTo: emailIndex)) + "..."
                }
            }
            feedbackDateLabel.text = feedback?.timeStamp.getFirstChar(10)
            userFeedbackLabel.text = feedback?.feedbackString
            if let avatarURLString = feedback?.avatar {
                let imageURL = URL(string: avatarURLString)
                gravatarImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)
            }
            roundedCorner()
}
}
}
```

Actually, I am getting all the feedback from the users and I want the user feedback at the topmost cell so that I can implement edit and delete feedback functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right you want to introduce a different cell at the tableView, which will be unique from the rest of the cells and placed on top, correct? That being said you need a second UITableViewCell, after doing this, in the method : cellForRowAt do

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
   let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TopCellId, for indexPath) as! TopCell

//here you update NewCell's properties with your code

return cell
} else {
  let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RegularCellId, for: indexPath) as! RegularCell

// Here you update the cell which will be used for the rest of the tableView

return cell
}
```

Might be the case that you can use a TableViewHeader as well, but your question it's a little confusing.

Comment: Atually, i want that unique cell along with others too

Comment: What do you mean, along with others? To not be separated by the tableView's line?

Answer (score 0):

Create two sections for the table:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2

}
```

Number of rows for each section are independent of each other:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {

    case 0:
        return feedbacks.count

    case 1:
        return someArray.count

    default:
        return 0

    }

}
```

And then load your cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let p = indexPath.row

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 0:

        let cell = FeedbackTableViewCell()
        cell.someLabel.text = feedbacks[p].someProperty
        return cell

    case 1:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: someReusableCellId, for: indexPath) as! SomeReusableTableViewCell
        cell.someLabel.text = someArray[p].someProperty
        return cell

    default:
        return UITableViewCell()

    }

}
```

You will need two different cell types for this because I assume the feedback cell won't look like the other cells. Notice that I didn't dequeue the feedback cell, I just instantiated it; that's because the cell will never be reused so don't bother registering and queueing it.